# How to pass date values in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

> By default the values are coming like this

activated_date.date_value as "Activated Date",
completed_date.date_value as "Completed Date",

> 2015-11-25 05:34:57   2015-11-25 05:35:03
>
> How to pass date value in MM/dd/YYYY format for a package body
>   Here is the package body

pkg_campaign_interactions_qty.getCampaignIncomingQty(Obj.object_id,to_date(to_char(activated_date.date_value,'MM/dd/YYYY'),'MM/dd/YYYY'),to_date(to_char(completed_date.date_value,'MM/dd/YYYY'),'MM/dd/YYYY'))as "Interactions"

> I tried to pass date values  this format getting ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
to_date(activated_date.date_value,'MM/dd/YYYY') as "Activated Date",to_date(completed_date.date_value,'MM/dd/YYYY') as "Completed Date",
```

> This is my package body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "PKG_CAMPAIGN_INTERACTIONS_QTY" as FUNCTION getCampaignIncomingQty(tableName IN VARCHAR2,ActivatedDate IN DATE,CompletedDate IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER end PKG_CAMPAIGN_INTERACTIONS_QTY;
```

/

Comment: A date does not have any format. A date is a date, period. If you have a **string** in format `2015-11-25 05:34:57`, you can convert it to a date by `TO_DATE('2015-11-25 05:34:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi.ss')`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specification of `pkg_campaign_interactions_qty.getCampaignIncomingQty` (seems like it takes dates, based on your other comments?) and the type of the two `date_value` columns.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get means that the value you are trying to turn into a date does not have the format specified.

```
to_date(activated_date.date_value,'MM/dd/YYYY')
```

Will only give you a date when activated_date.date_value is a string that contains a date in MM/dd/YYYY format.

Not a valid month indicates that the value of the first part of the string is not a number between 1 and 12.

Based on the sample you gave you should use:

```
to_date(activated_date.date_value,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

So if you have a function that has an input parameter of type date, you can call it in the following way:

```
create or replace my_function(p_date date) return number...

declare
  my_number number;
  my_date_string1 varchar2(20);
  my_date_string2 varchar2(20);
begin

  -- some string representing dates in different formats.
  my_date_string1 := '2015-12-01';
  my_date_string2 := '15/11/2015';

  -- Call the function. Make sure to convert the string into a
  -- date using the correct format.
  my_number := my_function(to_date(my_date_string1,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  my_number := my_function(to_date(my_date_string2,'DD/MM/YYYY'));
end;
```

Comment: The parameter is of date type once its converted to to_char(o_date('2015-11-25 05:34:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')  format i need to again pass this date to package body function which is of date type

Comment: Once you have a date type why convert it back to char?

Comment: I need to pass in pkg_campaign_interactions_qty.getCampaignIncomingQty(Obj.object_id,Activated date,Completed date ))as "Interactions" which accepts the date format as MM/dd/YYYY

Comment: Your answer is in my answer. Use the format I gave you and then convert to char using the other format.

Comment: But the package i have created is CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "PKG_CAMPAIGN_INTERACTIONS_QTY" as

FUNCTION getCampaignIncomingQty(tableName IN VARCHAR2,ActivatedDate IN DATE,CompletedDate IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER;

end PKG_CAMPAIGN_INTERACTIONS_QTY;
/ which is of date type

Comment: if you have a string that contains '2015-11-25 05:34:57' and you want a date, use to_date function with format mask 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I'm sure you can work the rest out for yourself.

Comment: The 2 dates activated date and completed date are masked in this format MM/dd/YYYY so need to convert to MM/dd/YYYY format using to_char then back to to_date for passing in package body i am unable to do so

Comment: No ! The parameter is a date. A date does not have a format. Only a string representing a date has a format. I will edit my answer.